# Prove $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} x \sin^2 x$ does not exist.

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

I need to prove $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} x \sin^2 x$ does not exist, and request your help verifying my argument is correct. I've got somewhat decent  at making $\epsilon-\delta$ arguments, but proving a limit does not exist has been a bit challenging actually.

We need to prove $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} x \sin^2 x \neq \ell$, for every $\ell \in \mathbb{R}$, so take $\ell \in \mathbb{R}$. The result follows if we can find some $\epsilon > 0$ such that for every $N \in \mathbb{R}$, there is some real $x$ such that $x > N$ but $\lvert x \sin^2 x - \ell \rvert \geq \epsilon$.

If $\epsilon =\lvert \ell \rvert + 1$, then for every $N \in \mathbb{R}$ we can find $x_0 > \max(N, \quad 2\lvert \ell \rvert + 1)$ such that $x_0 = \cfrac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi k$, for some big enough $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. For this $x_0$ we have that
$$x_0 \sin^2 x_0 = x_0 \cdot 1 = x_0 > 2\lvert \ell \rvert + 1 \geq 1 + \lvert \ell \rvert + \ell$$.
This implies $x_0 \sin^2 x_0 - \ell = x_0 - \ell > 1 + \lvert \ell \rvert = \epsilon$ and the proof is complete.

Any comments or suggestions for improvement are very appreciated.

Comment: This proves that it can't have a finite limit.  It's also possible to talk about whether the limit is $\infty$.  Are you familiar with that definition?  In this case, that doesn't work either.  Can you see why?

Comment: @RobertShore Yes I know the definition and yes you are right, it does not cover that case. However I think it is intuitively clear why the limit is not $\infty$: no mater how big is the number $L$ we can always find $x_1 = 2\pi k$, for a big $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, which will bring the function back to zero. I think I can formalize this argument.

Comment: Good.  So I'd formalize that and add it to your proof.

Comment: @RobertShore Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your argument is fine, though as mentioned in the comments you don't address the possibility that the limit is infinite.

Here is a slightly simpler idea. Given any $k>0$, then $x_k=\frac\pi2+2k\pi>k$ and $x_k\sin^2x_k=x_k>k$. Also $z_k=2k\pi>k$ and $z_k\sin^2z_k=0$. So
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}x_k\sin^2x_k=\infty,
$$
while
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}z_k\sin^2z_k=0.
$$
This precludes the existence of the limit (finite or infinite), since if it existed all sequences that go to infinity would give the same limit.

Answer (score -1):

This is just a variation of Martin Argerami's answer. He constructed a sequence $(x_k)$ such that $\lim_{k\to\infty}x_k\sin^2x_k=\infty$. Let us show that for each $a \in [0,\infty)$ there exists a sequence $(y_k)$ such that
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}y_k\sin^2y_k=a .$$

We have $\sin^2 x = 0$ for $x = m\pi$ and $\sin^2 x = 1$ for $x = \pi/2 + m\pi$ for all $m \in \mathbb Z$. Thus by the IVT the function $f(x) = x \sin^2x$ maps the interval $[m\pi, \pi/2 + m\pi]$ onto the interval $[0,\pi/2 + m\pi]$. Hence for $m \ge m_0 = \max(0,(a-2)/\pi)$ we find a point $y_m \in [m\pi, \pi/2 + m\pi]$ such that $f(y_m) = a$. Let $y_m = m\pi$ for $m < m_0$. Then clearly $y_m \to \infty$ as $m \to  \infty$ and $\lim_{m\to\infty}y_m\sin^2y_m=a$.

Comment: What is wrong with this answer that it was downvoted?